# JavaScript function does not output anything on html file

Tags: javascript, html

Hey all a stupid question here. 
This is my code:

```
function showDay(){
    var t = newDate();
    var dayz = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    document.getElementById('kappa').innerHTML = dayz[t.getDay()];
}
```

In my HTML file I have  for where I want this function to output. However it does not work. I know the JS file is referenced properly as my other functions work just fine.

Any help appreciated! Sorry for being such a rookie.

Comment: `newDate()` ✗  |  `new Date()` ✓

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="kappa">
        </div>

      <script>
      var t = new Date();
          var dayz = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
          document.getElementById('kappa').innerHTML = dayz[t.getDay()];
      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code on Jsfiddle I could run it ... Hope this helps

```
 var t = new Date();
    var dayz = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    alert(dayz[t.getDay()]);
```

if you still have more issues I would like to see html

Comment: The HTML is located above the <script></script> tags and says <div id="kappa"></div> there is a lot of other code on the page as well but it seems to working fine with everything but the date.

Comment: leave a space between new and Date ... write as "new Date()" it should do the magic as shown in above code